# Unicode Characters not being saved when inserting from VB6

Tags: sql-server, unicode, vb6, character-encoding

I have a VB6 application and when trying to save unicode charcters these are not being saved properly in the Ms SQL database. When executing the insert statment directly in SSMS the insert is performed correctly.

`Exec sp_Insert_item 1, 101, N'Ħass'`

I am using the SQLOLEDB as driver in my connection string and my columns are set as NVarchar's

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that VB6 will support unicode. In fact, VB6 strings are inherently unicode but the problem is that it gets lost in translation when displayed / retrieved from user controls which do not properly support it.

If you are obtaining the string from the UI, ensure to use textbox controls that support it. For example, add a reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library and use these controls over the regular textbox control that comes out of the box.  This way you can set the font type and script to one which supports unicode.

You may also wish to check out some of the built in functions for manipulating your unicode strings such as "StrConv", "ChrW$", etc.

Comment: The UNICODE Characters are not being lost when retrieving / displaying the data in the textboxes. But when trying to write to the SQL server.  
My code is like the below and it still doesn't work the text "Ħass" has been retrieved properly from the text box;  
`Set CreateRecordset = New adodb.Recordset  
CreateRecordset.Open "Exec sp_Insert_item 1, 101, N'Ħass'", conn, adOpenForwardOnly`

Comment: @WarrenRox: If their entering text in their local code page, then it will get into the VB code correctly. You only need to replace the controls when entering text in different code pages.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem relates to the same ANSI-only problem within VB6 source code String literals that we run into with most of the available controls.

Your:

```
CreateRecordset.Open "Exec sp_Insert_item 1, 101, N'Ħass'", conn, adOpenForwardOnly
```

Is actually:

```
CreateRecordset.Open "Exec sp_Insert_item 1, 101, N'Hass'", conn, adOpenForwardOnly
```

... after you paste it in there.

This is a common enough sort of thing that I often use a Class I call `EscerLite` to help deal with this.  Of course it operates at run time, sadly enough, but it often beats the alternative of concatenating ChrW$() calls within my String literals in code.

I usually edit the .CLS file so that `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True` which results in a global, predeclared instance (much as VB6 .FRM modules do, which is where the "free" Form instance named for the module name come from).  But you don't have to do that of course.

It has one method defined: `UnEscape` while my full version `Escer` also has an `Escape` method that goes the "other way" - useful for serialization of settings and such.

This lets you write:

```
CreateRecordset.Open EscerLite.UnEscape("Exec sp_Insert_item 1, 101, N'^u0126ass'"), _
                     conn, _
                     adOpenForwardOnly
```

But you could cook up your own scheme, or just use ChrW$() calls.

**EscerLite.cls**

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum UnEscStates
    uesNotInEscapeSeq = 0
    uesProcessingEscSeq = 1
    uesProcessingLongEscSeq = 2
    uesProcessingLongEscSeqXEnd = 3
    uesProcessingLongEscSeqUEnd = 5
End Enum

Public Function UnEscape(ByVal EscapedText As String) As String
    'Un-escape a string value.  Escape sequences supported:
    '
    '   ^xhh   7 bit hex               ^r     vbCr
    '   ^uhhhh 16 bit hex ("Unicode")  ^l     vbLf
    '   ^b     vbBack                  ^n     vbNewLine/vbCrLf
    '   ^t     vbTab                   ^q     quote (")
    '   ^v     vbVerticalTab           ^0     vbNullChar
    '   ^f     vbFormFeed              ^^     ^

    Dim Pos As Long
    Dim ChS As String
    Dim ChW As Integer
    Dim UpChW As Integer
    Dim UnEscState As UnEscStates
    Dim UnPos As Long
    Dim Unicode As Boolean
    Dim Accum As Long

    UnEscape = Space$(Len(EscapedText))
    UnPos = 1&
    For Pos = 1& To Len(EscapedText)
        ChS = Mid$(EscapedText, Pos, 1&)
        ChW = AscW(ChS)
        UpChW = AscW(UCase$(ChS))
        Select Case UnEscState
            Case uesNotInEscapeSeq
                If ChW = 94# Then ' "^"
                    UnEscState = uesProcessingEscSeq
                End If
            Case uesProcessingEscSeq
                UnEscState = uesNotInEscapeSeq
                Select Case UpChW
                    Case 88# ' "X"
                        UnEscState = uesProcessingLongEscSeq
                    Case 85# ' "U"
                        Unicode = True
                        UnEscState = uesProcessingLongEscSeq
                    Case 66# ' "B"
                        ChS = vbBack
                    Case 84# ' "T"
                        ChS = vbTab
                    Case 86# ' "V"
                        ChS = vbVerticalTab
                    Case 70# ' "F"
                        ChS = vbFormFeed
                    Case 82# ' "R"
                        ChS = vbCr
                    Case 76# ' "L"
                        ChS = vbLf
                    Case 78# ' "N"
                        Mid$(UnEscape, UnPos, 1&) = vbCr
                        UnPos = UnPos + 1
                        ChS = vbLf
                    Case 81# ' "Q"
                        ChS = """"
                    Case 48# ' "0"
                        ChS = vbNullChar
                    Case 94# ' "^", i.e. ^^
                        '
                    Case Else
                        Err.Raise 5
                End Select
            Case Else
                If (48# <= UpChW And UpChW <= 57#) Then
                    Accum = 16& * Accum + (CLng(UpChW) And &HF&)
                ElseIf (65# <= UpChW And UpChW <= 70#) Then
                    Accum = 16& * Accum + (CLng(UpChW) - 55&)
                Else
                    Err.Raise 5
                End If
                UnEscState = UnEscState + 1&
                If Unicode Then
                    If UnEscState > uesProcessingLongEscSeqUEnd Then
                        ChS = ChrW$(Accum)
                        Accum = 0&
                        UnEscState = uesNotInEscapeSeq
                        Unicode = False
                    End If
                Else
                    If Accum > 127 Then Err.Raise 5
                    If UnEscState > uesProcessingLongEscSeqXEnd Then
                        ChS = ChrW$(Accum)
                        Accum = 0&
                        UnEscState = uesNotInEscapeSeq
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
        If UnEscState = uesNotInEscapeSeq Then
            Mid$(UnEscape, UnPos, 1&) = ChS
            UnPos = UnPos + 1&
        End If
    Next
    If UnEscState <> uesNotInEscapeSeq Then Err.Raise 5
    UnEscape = Left$(UnEscape, UnPos - 1&)
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, as the characters that I have for example 'Ħ' are not being saved in the database as 'H' but as 'ÄÄ'.